# Curl and Product Rule

Tags: vector-analysis

I know the famous identity

$\nabla \times (\vec{A} \times \vec{B}) = A(\nabla \cdot \vec{B}) -B(\nabla \cdot \vec{A}) + (B\cdot \nabla) \vec{A}- (A\cdot \nabla) \vec{B}$

My question: Can I distribute the curl like a normal differential operator as follows:

$\nabla \times (\vec{A} \times \vec{B}) =(\nabla \times \vec{A})\times B + (\nabla \times \vec{B})\times A$

With the del operator acting only on A in $(\nabla \times \vec{A})\times \vec{B}$ and only acting on B in the second term?

Or are there any "product rules" for the curl of a cross product other than the well-known one I gave in the beginning?

EDIT:

I posted the question because in the solution to my homework we are given the following equation which I don't understand:

$\nabla \times (\vec{e}_r \times \phi \vec{A}) = (\nabla \phi)\times (\vec{e}_r \times \vec{A})$ with the radial unit vector $\vec{e}_r$ and $\nabla \times \vec{A}=0$.

So does anyone have an idea where this comes from, then?

Comment: Surely the proposed identity cannot hold, as the l.h.s. is skew in $\bf A$ and $\bf B$ but the r.h.s. is symmetric in them.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_(mathematics)#Identities

Comment: Thank you, I already checked Wikipedia but it doesn't help me with my problem.

Answer (score 4):

No. Choose some simple parallel vectors like $$\vec A = \vec B = \langle x, x, x\rangle$$
Then $\vec A \times \vec B = \vec 0$, but

$$\nabla \times \vec A = \langle 0, -1, 1\rangle$$
so that
$$(\nabla \times \vec A) \times \vec B = \langle -2x, x, x\rangle$$

---

I'm not aware of any similar rules that involve only curl, although there is a product rule for multiplying by a *scalar* function, e.g. $\nabla (f \vec A)$. Some identities for second derivatives are given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities#Curl_2) as well.

Comment: Thanks, please look at my edit. I added the equation that led me to my original question, perhaps this makes it clearer...

Answer (score 0):

There is a general fact about derivatives that seems to not be as widely known as it should: *the derivative of an expression is the sum of the derivatives of its subexpression*. Applying this fact requires precisely keeping track of what is being differentiated, so I will use the following convention: $\nabla$ acts as it usually does, but $\dot\nabla$ only differentiates other dotted variables. The dot notation is powerful since *all vectors identities are valid even with $\dot\nabla$* so long as we properly keep track of differentiation like this and so long as $\dot\nabla$ appears in a linear slot.

As a good example of all this in action, let's consider your last equation. As best as I can tell, this just isn't true; what is true though is
$$
  \nabla\cdot(e_r\times(\phi A)) = (\nabla\phi)\cdot(e_r\times A)
$$
so perhaps it was a typo. More generally,
$$
  \nabla\cdot(A\times(\phi B)) = (\nabla\phi)\cdot(A\times B)
\tag{$*$}
$$
for any $A, B$ with $\nabla\times A = 0$ and $\nabla\times B = 0$. To see why, start with
$$
  \nabla\cdot(A\times(\phi B))
    = \dot\nabla\cdot(\dot A\times(\dot\phi\dot B))
    = \dot\nabla\cdot(\dot A\times(\phi B)) + \dot\nabla\cdot(A\times(\dot\phi B)) + \dot\nabla\cdot(A\times(\phi\dot B)).
$$
Since $\phi$ is a scalar quantity, the second term is
$$
  \dot\nabla\cdot(A\times(\dot\phi B)) = (\nabla\phi)\cdot(A\times B),
$$
so we need to show that the two other terms sum to $0$. In fact, they are both individually $0$; consider that the triple product is stable under cyclic permutations:
$$
  a\cdot(b\times c) = c\cdot(a\times b) = b\cdot(c\times a).
$$
Thus
$$
  \dot\nabla\cdot(\dot A\times(\phi B)) = \phi B\cdot(\dot\nabla\times\dot A) = 0,
$$$$
  \dot\nabla\cdot(A\times(\phi\dot B)) = \phi A\cdot(\dot B\times\dot\nabla) = 0,
$$
proving ($*$).

---

This is also how we can prove your first equation. Using the identity
$$
  a\times(b\times c) =  (a\cdot c)b - (a\cdot b)c
$$
we see
$$\begin{aligned}
  \nabla\times(A\times B)
    &= \dot\nabla\times(\dot A\times B) + \dot\nabla\times(A\times\dot B)
\\
    &= (\dot\nabla\cdot B)\dot A - (\dot\nabla\cdot\dot A)B + (\dot\nabla\cdot\dot B)A - (\dot\nabla\cdot A)\dot B
\\
    &= (B\cdot\nabla)A - (\nabla\cdot A)B + (\nabla\cdot B)A - (A\cdot\nabla)B.
\end{aligned}$$

---

Your second equation is false simply because
$$
  a\times(b\times c) \not= (a\times b)\times c.
$$
However, we do have the Jacobi identity
$$
  a\times(b\times c) + c\times(a\times b) + b\times(c\times a) = 0,
$$
so applying this the best we can say is
$$\begin{aligned}
  \nabla\times(A\times B)
    &= \dot\nabla(\dot A\times B) + \dot\nabla(A\times\dot B)
\\
    &= -B\times(\dot\nabla\times\dot A) - \dot A\times(B\times\dot\nabla) - \dot B\times(\dot\nabla\times A) - A\times(\dot B\times\dot\nabla)
\\
    &= (\nabla\times A)\times B + A\times(\nabla\times B) + (B\times\nabla)\times A- (A\times\nabla)\times B
\end{aligned}$$
so the degree to which your identity fails is measured by the term
$$
  (B\times\nabla)\times A- (A\times\nabla)\times B.
$$

Answer (score 0):

We can prove an identity for the curl of a cross product directly using the [Einstein summation convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation#). Observe that \begin{align*}
\boldsymbol \nabla \times (\mathbf A \times \mathbf B)  &= \varepsilon_{ijk} \partial_i[\mathbf A \times \mathbf B]_j \mathbf e_k \tag{1} \\
&= \varepsilon_{ijk} \partial_i(\varepsilon_{pqj}A_pB_q)\mathbf e_k \tag{2}\\
&= \varepsilon_{jki}\varepsilon_{jpq} \partial_i A_p B_q \mathbf e_k \tag{3}\\ 
&= \varepsilon_{jki}\varepsilon_{jpq}\Big(\partial_i(A_p)B_q + A_p \partial_i(B_q)\Big)\mathbf e_k \tag{4}\\
&= (\delta_{kp} \delta_{iq} - \delta_{kq} \delta_{ip})\Big(\partial_i(A_p)B_q + A_p \partial_i(B_q)\Big)\mathbf e_k \tag{5}\\
&= \partial_i(A_k)B_i\mathbf e_k + A_k\partial _i(B_i)\mathbf e_k - \partial_i(A_i)B_k \mathbf e_k - A_i \partial_i(B_k)\mathbf e_k \tag{6}\\
&= B_i\partial_i(A_k \mathbf e_k) - (\partial_iA_i)B_k\mathbf e_k+ (\partial_iB_i)A_k \mathbf e_k - (A_i\partial_i)B_k \mathbf e_k \tag{7}\\
&= (\mathbf B \boldsymbol \cdot \boldsymbol \nabla)\mathbf A - (\boldsymbol \nabla \boldsymbol \cdot \mathbf A)\mathbf B + (\boldsymbol \nabla \boldsymbol \cdot \mathbf B)\mathbf A - (\mathbf A \boldsymbol \cdot \boldsymbol \nabla)\mathbf B,\tag{8}
\end{align*}
where

- $(1)$ follows since $\boldsymbol \nabla \times \mathbf F = \varepsilon_{ijk} \partial_iF_j \mathbf e_k$;
- $(2)$ follows since $\mathbf F \times \mathbf G = \varepsilon_{ijk}F_iG_j\mathbf e_k$;
- $(3)$ follows since $\varepsilon_{ijk}=\varepsilon_{jki}=\varepsilon_{kij}$;
- $(4)$ follows by the product rule;
- $(5)$ follows by the epsilon contraction identity $\varepsilon_{ijk}\varepsilon_{ipq} = (\delta_{jp}\delta_{kq} - \delta_{jq} \delta_{kp})$;
- $(6)$ follows by the delta contraction identity $\delta_{ij}a_j = a_i$;
- $(7)$ follows by shifting terms around, noting that derivatives act on the right;
- $(8)$ follows since $(\mathbf F \boldsymbol \cdot \boldsymbol \nabla)\mathbf G = F_i\partial_iG_j\mathbf e_j$ and $\boldsymbol \nabla \boldsymbol \cdot \mathbf F = \partial_iF_i$.